# Heroku - 'bash' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: heroku

I have installed Heroku on my windows pc (heroku-windows-amd64).
When I try to enter heroku command in my command line I get error "'bash' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."
I read that restarting command line, restarting pc helps, but it did not in this instance. I tried reinstalling, restarting pc multiple times. Could anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "[What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)". Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

Add heroku directory to your `PATH` variables e.g. `C:\Program Files\Heroku\bin`